# Laravel: get users created more than three months ago

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel app I want to get all records of users where "created_at" timestamp is older than three months from current date, is it possible to achieve this with Eloquent query builder?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Do you want users that are created before, after, or exactly on the date you mention? Also this is a rather trivial operation to do with just some basic reading through the documentation of Laravel. Have you actually tried anything and failed and if so what?

Answer (score 3):

First, you can use Carbon to get the date of 3 months ago.

```
$date = Carbon::now()->subMonths(3)->format('Y-m-d');
```

And then we need all the records before that that. So, query should be-

```
$users = User::where('created_at', '<=', $date)->get();
```

Comment: Wrong comparator

Comment: You don't need to format the date, You can pass Carbon instance directly into Eloquent query

Answer (score 0):

belowe code can help you to solve problem

```
$three_month = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth(3);
 $data = DB::table('orders')
                    ->where('placed_at','>',$three_month)
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent can compare datetimes. You can use Carbon to get the date you want to compare to and use it in your eloquent query.

```
$threeMonthsAgo = now()->subMonth(3);    
$users = User::where('created_at', '<' , $threeMonthsAgo)->get();
```

Comment: You might want to swap that symbol.  Created at must be smaller than three months

Comment: oh, you are correct @Snapey

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateS = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth(3);
$dateE = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(); 
$usersArr = $users
->whereBetween('created_at',[$dateS,$dateE])
->get();
```

startOfMonth() begins with 1st date of the month

Comment: Why use `startOfMonth()`?

Comment: To exactly start it from the first date of the month

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make it done by using carbon. Use the below code-

```
User::where( 'created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(3))->get();
```

Comment: Wrong comparator

Comment: I don't think so. `Carbon::now()->subMonths(3)` will return the date of previous 3 months from today. Then it will return the data after that date . That means older than three months from current date. I hope you get it.

Comment: You need the created at to be SMALLER than three months ago to be EARLIER

Comment: Okay , yes. I thought he wanted only data of last 3months from current date. Then it was correct.  I read the question again. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

To find users older than three months

```
$users = User::where('created_at','<', today()->subMonths(3))->get();
```